How to configure Jenkins with Nginx
I have a Nginx server and i want to add a server for Jenkins so i create a jenkins.conf file in /etc/nginx/conf.d :
upstream jenkins {
  keepalive 32; # keepalive connections
  server 127.0.0.1:8080; # jenkins ip and port
}

# Required for Jenkins websocket agents
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}

server {
  listen          80;       # Listen on port 80 for IPv4 requests

  server_name     jenkins.example.com;  # replace 'jenkins.example.com' with your server domain name

  # this is the jenkins web root directory
  # (mentioned in the output of "systemctl cat jenkins")
  root            /var/run/jenkins/war/;

  access_log      /var/log/nginx/jenkins.access.log;
  error_log       /var/log/nginx/jenkins.error.log;

  # pass through headers from Jenkins that Nginx considers invalid
  ignore_invalid_headers off;

  location ~ "^/static/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\/(.*)$" {
    # rewrite all static files into requests to the root
    # E.g /static/12345678/css/something.css will become /css/something.css
    rewrite "^/static/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\/(.*)" /$1 last;
  }

  location /userContent {
    # have nginx handle all the static requests to userContent folder
    # note : This is the $JENKINS_HOME dir
    root /var/lib/jenkins/;
    if (!-f $request_filename){
      # this file does not exist, might be a directory or a /**view** url
      rewrite (.*) /$1 last;
      break;
    }
    sendfile on;
  }

  location / {
      sendfile off;
      proxy_pass         http://jenkins;
      proxy_redirect     default;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;

      # Required for Jenkins websocket agents
      proxy_set_header   Connection        $connection_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header   Upgrade           $http_upgrade;

      proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

      #this is the maximum upload size
      client_max_body_size       10m;
      client_body_buffer_size    128k;

      proxy_connect_timeout      90;
      proxy_send_timeout         90;
      proxy_read_timeout         90;
      proxy_request_buffering    off; # Required for HTTP CLI commands
  }

}

I replace the server name by is mine like jenkins.my-domain.com, it's a subdomain.
But i don't understand it doesn't work it display the same index.html that my other server.
Thank you for your help !
I have put the conf file also in /etc/nginx/site-available and doesn't work also.

Putting config in /etc/nginx/sites-available has no effect, those files are not included. If you check your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf you can see that it needs to be in either /etc/nginx/conf.d (as you did) or /etc/nginx/sites-enabled (conventionally different site configs go there as links to the actuals configs in /etc/nginx/sites-available). What's your other site config? Only listen and server_name parameters are relevant.

thanks for your reply, i was mistaken, i have put the conf for jenkins in conf.d, nothing work and also put in sites-enabled, and nothing also.
But i don't put the file conf in sites-available

i have a different error now :
HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found
URI: /
STATUS: 404
MESSAGE: Not Found
SERVLET: -
Powered by Jetty:// 10.0.20

What's the URL of your Jenkins without nginx? Do you have context path configured? https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/reverse-proxy-configuration-with-jenkins/reverse-proxy-configuration-nginx/#context-path

Thank you man it's works !!! I have a prefix /jenkins
